Movie where kids used a bed frame and bullet to threaten someone
I may have only seen a commercial/trailer, but the imagery is still with me today decades later. I believe I saw this in the later 1980's.  There were three children or youth.  One was holding another person still, while the other had a bullet in a nook or hole in a bedframe (perhaps it was some other furniture), and a nail and hammer to set off the bullet.  I believe the two were attempting to threaten the third in some way.
Details:

Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in?

I saw at least this portion on broadcast TV in the US, in English.

Was it an American production, or from a different country?

I don't know the production, however I believe it was set in a war-torn UK. The setting was a room in shambles, glass blown out of windows, dirt everywhere.  The youth were dirty, unkempt, and notably thin or malnourished.

Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? 

Real life, color.

We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

@DForck42 I've added answers to your specific questions. I realize I don't have a lot of clues for others to go on, here, so I'll answer what questions I can but I recognize it may still be closed due to insufficient information.

Found it, and marked as duplicate since additional google footwork led me back to the right answer here.  Thank's for reminding me of the community standards, @DForck42 !

Heh, nice!  glad you found your answer!
